# on selecting the dropdownlist 2 nd time textbox value not showing blank

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written following code.

my 1st orderid has both records for process 1 and process 2
but my 2nd orderid has record only for process 1.

when i select orderid 2 after selecting orderid 1 it keeps the value as it is for orderid 1 in process 2 textbox.
i want that textbox to be blank

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DbConnect objdbc = new DbConnect();
    SqlConnection con = objdbc.openConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [orderid],[processid],[orgid],[processdesc] ,[perwet] FROM [anghan].[dbo].[ProcessOrder] where orderid='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value + "' and processid=1 ", con);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", value);
    cmd.Connection = con;
    //con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        TextBox2.Text = dr["perwet"].ToString();
        //  DropDownList1.Items(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex).Text = dr["service"].ToString();
    }
    dr.Close();
    //process 2

    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [orderid],[processid],[orgid],[processdesc] ,[perwet] FROM [anghan].[dbo].[ProcessOrder] where orderid='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value + "' and processid=2 ", con);

    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", value);
    cmd2.Connection = con;
    //con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr2.Read())
    {

        TextBox3.Text = dr2["perwet"].ToString();
        //  DropDownList1.Items(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex).Text = dr["service"].ToString();
    }
    dr2.Close();
```

Comment: please elaborate more. It seems to be confused.

Comment: I agree , question need more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do not you set the TextBox2 and TextBox3 to empty in the starting of the code . So that you do see what you have populated . Only those textbox value will be change where your code will reassign otherwise it will keep the old value.

Answer (score 0):

```
just put like this>>



 if(dr!=null)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
            {
                if((dr["perwet"]!=null)||(dr["perwet"].ToString()!=""))
                TextBox2.Text = dr["perwet"].ToString();
                else
                TextBox2.Text="";


                //  DropDownList1.Items(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex).Text = dr["service"].ToString();
            }
    }
```

It will work.

Comment: check for NULL condition first (dr["perwet"]!=null , otherwise you may get the error

Comment: I think , it becomes one and the same, if dr["perwet"]=null then (dr["perwet"].toString() must be "".[Not sure, but it seems]

Comment: @Freelancer No. You are wrong about that. You would get a `NullPointerException` if you call `ToString` on a null object.

Comment: no but if C# will try to check for the first condition .tostring will through the exception as , this is not possible on the NULL object

Comment: ohh, thanks devesh for valuable information. please see the code edit.

Comment: in my code it is giving Invalid attempt to call MetaData when reader is closed.

Comment: put debugger with your code, and see actuall flow and tell me the point at which problem is comming.

Comment: when i select the dropdownlist for the 2  nd time it is not executing following block at all

while (dr.Read())
    {
        if((dr["perwet"]!=null)||(dr["perwet"].ToString()!=""))
        TextBox2.Text = dr["perwet"].ToString();
        else
        TextBox2.Text="";


        //  DropDownList1.Items(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex).Text = dr["service"].ToString();
    }

Comment: It is not executing because , htere is nothing in datareader at that time. i.e. where conditions in sql query are not satisfying or giving any output at that particular instance.

Comment: write additional if condition that i hav wrote in my edited code.